# Xamarin Forms - IOS , Scripts and styles are not calling

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin forms IOS application calling HTML pages, styles and scripts by using Hybrid WebView. I am not able to render styles and scripts and my code is

HybridWebViewRenderer.cs

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        if (Control == null) {
            userController = new WKUserContentController ();
            var script = new WKUserScript (new NSString (JavaScriptFunction), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, false);
            userController.AddUserScript (script);
            userController.AddScriptMessageHandler (this, "invokeAction");

            var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };
            var webView = new WKWebView (Frame, config);
            SetNativeControl (webView);
        }

        if (e.OldElement != null) {
            userController.RemoveAllUserScripts ();
            userController.RemoveScriptMessageHandler ("invokeAction");
            var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
            hybridWebView.Cleanup ();
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null) {
            string fileName = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, string.Format ("Content/{0}", Element.Uri));

           //fileName = "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2DC89563-D118-4092-B7A5-4549AF07F3B2/StoneApplication.iOS.app/Content/index.html"

            Control.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl (fileName, false)));
        }
    }

    public void DidReceiveScriptMessage (WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
    {
        Element.InvokeAction (message.Body.ToString ());
    }
```

and my index.html, here I am calling scripts, Images and styles

```
<html>
<head>
<title>STONEAPP TEMPLATE</title>
<!--Scripts-->
<script src="/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/fileServer.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/app.js"></script>

<!--Styles-->
<link href="/Styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body ng-app="stoneApp" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
<div ng-controller="templateCtrl">
    <div id="Header" style="background-color:#293846;min-height:50px">
        <table style="width:100%;padding-top:5px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" width="5%" valign="middle" ng-if="jobView == true" ng-click="showActList()">
                    <img src="/Images/arrow-back.png" alt="" style="height:50px;width:50px"/>
                </td>
                <td align="center" width="5%" valign="middle">
                    <img src="/Images/wifi_on.png" alt="" style="height:50px;width:50px" ng-click="ShowWifiSettings()"/>
                </td>
                <td align="center" width="5%" valign="middle" ng-click="ShowTabSettings()">
                    <img src="/Images/settings.png" alt="" style="height:50px;width:50px" ng-if="loginView == false"/>
                </td>
                <td width="5%" valign="middle" ng-if="activityView == true"></td>
                <td width="60%" valign="middle"></td>
                <td width="20%" valign="middle" align="right">
                    <span style="color:white" ng-if="loginView == false">{{userName}} !</span>
                </td>
                <td width="5%" align="right" valign="middle" ng-click="logout()" >
                    <img src="/Images/power_button.png" style="height:50px;width:50px" ng-if="loginView == false"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

I gave build action as bundle resource for styles and scripts even though I am not able to call styles and scripts and program structure is as attached image.

[image]

I am using iOS 10.2 tablet. How can I investigate my issue and make call the scripts styles and images as the links given in the HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with `Control.LoadRequest`

You're problem is that you can't define baseUrl for your webview with this method and no other method let you define it.
So when your index.html is loaded into the webview, the webview can't retrieve script or css because the baseUrl is not defined and it doesn't know where to load them.

A workaround is to use `LoadHtmlString (String htmlContent, NSUrl baseUrl)`

Where `htmlContent` is your index.html content loaded into a var and baseUrl `NSUrl baseurl = new NSUrl(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, true);`

Comment: Hi @Leze  I add like this, but no luck scripts/css/images are not loading      string htmlPath = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, string.Format("Content/{0}", Element.Uri));
string htmlContents = File.ReadAllText(htmlPath);
Control.LoadHtmlString(htmlContents, null);

Comment: You're missing the baseUrl parameter in your LoadHtmlString. Try to do it like this `string htmlPath = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, string.Format("Content/{0}", Element.Uri)); NSUrl baseurl = new NSUrl(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, true); string htmlContents = File.ReadAllText(htmlPath); Control.LoadHtmlString(htmlContents, baseurl);`